# Add an index to see if a field is NULL

Tags: mysql, indexing, null

I have a field called synopsis, and a common lookup for me is to see if the synopsis has been provided:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE synopsis IS NOT NULL;
```

Would the following index be recommended to add for this query?

```
ALTER TABLE main_catalog ADD INDEX (synopsis(1));
```

Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the assumption is that `synopsis` is a character or binary field (length for an index is only available for these types).

An index on `synopsis` -- including an index with a prefix length of 1 -- will use an index for `is not null` (you might be interested in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/mysql-index-for-searching-for-null-values-in-text-fields) on Stack Exchange).

Whether this actually helps depends on the nature of the data.  For instance, if `synopsis` is never `NULL`, then accessing the data through the index is slightly slower and insert operations are slightly slower (the differences are quite minor in most cases).  On the other hand, if you only have synopses for 0.1% of the records, then the index should help improve performance for your query.